# Google chrome Version 72.0.3626.81 bug or code error?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, chromium

I have Google chrome Version 72.0.3626.81 where   not working but when i use Version 71 it works.

How to make the following work?

```
<img src="abcd/720p.jpg" usemap="map_sync" id="spmain">
<map name="map_sync" class="maps" id="map_sync">
        <area shape="rect" coords="225, 214, 1053, 298" nohref="" onclick="eid();">       
        <area shape="rect" coords="224, 319, 1052, 403" nohref="" onclick="no_eid();">                     
      </map>
```

None of the javascript methods are getting executed on version 72 stable but on 71 it works. i re-tested the alignment and the map alignment is also correct.

Is it a BUG or code issue?

Comment: is there any console errors?

Comment: NO - console error, its fixed by putting `#`

Comment: In version 71 i did not needed to put `#`.

Comment: Where specifically were you putting a # ?

Comment: FAIL 72 - `$('#spmain').attr('usemap', 'map_sync')`. WORKS 72 - FAIL - `$('#spmain').attr('usemap', '#map_sync');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Google chrome 72

```
FAIL 72 - $('#spmain').attr('usemap', 'map_sync');
WORKS 72 - $('#spmain').attr('usemap', '#map_sync');
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a # to the mapname does the trick for me.

This is how it looks for Jsf (Primefaces)

```
<p:commandLink rendered="#{user.calendar}" 
    oncomplete="PF('planningBoxDialog').show();" >
    <p:graphicImage
        value="#{appointment.planning.streamedContent}"
        id="streamedContent"
        cache="FALSE" usemap="#indicatorMap">
    </p:graphicImage>
</p:commandLink>
<map name="#indicatorMap">
    <area coords="0,0,10,10"
          title="#{appointment.planning.planningBoxTooltipTopLeft}"
                  onclick="rc_planning();"/>
    <area coords="10,0,20,10"
          title="#{appointment.planning.planningBoxTooltipTopRight}"
          onclick="rc_planning();"/>
    <area coords="0,10,10,20"
          title="#{appointment.planning.planningBoxTooltipBottomLeft}"
          onclick="rc_planning();"/>
    <area coords="10,10,20,20"
          title="#{appointment.planning.planningBoxTooltipBottomRight}"
          onclick="rc_planning();"/>
```